# Create Change Password page by JSP & Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I created a `Change Password` form using JSP, and a servlet page to manipulate data and enter it into the DB.
This is an internal website (intranet) therefore the DB already contains details about `Email, FName, LName` for all users. Only the password field is null. What I'm trying to do is, after the user fills in their email address, password, confirms it and then presses on the submit button, the servlet page should update the password field for the current Email. Unfortunately, in all cases the user seems to be redirected to `ChangeError.jsp`.
Please find enclosed both files.(`ChangePassword.JSP`  and `ChangePassword.Servlet`). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    //ChangePassword.jsp
    <FORM ACTION="ChangePassword" METHOD="GET">
<div id="login_box">
  <div id="login_header">
        Login
  </div>
  <div id="form_val">
    <div class="label">Email:</div>
    <div class="control"><input type="text" name="Email" id="Email"/></div>

    <div class="label">Password:</div>
    <div class="control"><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password"/></div>

    <div class="label">Confirm Password:</div>
    <div class="control"><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password"/></div>
    <div style="clear:both;height:0px;"></div>

    <div id="msgbox"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="login_footer">
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
  function closewindow() {
  window.close()
  }
  </script>-->
     <label>
    <input type="submit" onclick="location.href='http://localhost:8080/IntegrateAll/Index.jsp'" window.close();" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" class="send_button" />
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
    //ChangePassword.servlet        
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import javax.naming.*;
    public class ChangePassword extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public ChangePassword() {
    super();
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String Email = request.getParameter("Email");
    String Password = request.getParameter("Password");
    String CPassword = request.getParameter("Password");

    Connection con =   GetConnectToDb();
    boolean flag = CheckLogin(Password,CPassword,Email,con);
    if(flag==true){
        gotoPage("/LoginPage.jsp",request,response);
    }
    else{
        gotoPage("/ChangeError.jsp",request,response);
    }
}
public void gotoPage(String address, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(address);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
public boolean CheckLogin(String Password, String CPassword,String Email, Connection con) {
    if (Password != null && CPassword != null && Email !=null) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE PUBLIC.IAUSERS SET Password = ('"+Password+"') WHERE Email='"+Email+"'");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public Connection GetConnectToDb() {

    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        Connection con = null;
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/DefaultDS");
        con = ds.getConnection();
        return con;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }}
```

Comment: There are 3 possible ways for CheckLogin to return false: the first if condition being false, rs.next() being false, or an exception being thrown. Adding logging, or displaying a message for these possibilities would have made the problem easier to spot.

Answer (score 4):

An update query must be executed with `executeUpdate()`, not `executeQuery()`.

There are other problems in your code:

- you should use prepared statements instead of concatenation. This will avoid SQL injection attacks, and avoid errors if the password contains a single quote, for example.
- you should never use GET to post a form containing a password. This makes the password appear in clear text in the browser adress bar
- you should respect Java naming conventions: methods and variables start with a lower-case letter
- you should always close the connection in a finally block. Else, after N executions, your connection pool won't have any available connection anymore, and you'll have to restart the application every minute
- You should never catch Exception and never never ignore the exception completely.
- `if (flag == true)` is ugly. Use `if (flag)`
- A given HTML pages should never have two elements with the same `id` attribute. An ID is supposed to be unique.
- you don't use the CPassword parameter at all.
- the methods should be private by default, unless you have a very good reason to make them public.

Comment: Hello JB, Thanks for your response. I tried to change excecuteQuery() to excecuteUpdate() but I got an error saying that rs must be an int. I know that something is missing but because I'm new with JAVA I don't know how to solve it. Could you please help me with the SERVLET file, What I'm doing wrong or what is missing in my code? I'll appreciate if you attach a code example. regarding all other changes, I'll fix it.

Comment: Read the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29